# simple JSON.parse error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a string that pull off the DOM that looks like so: `product_category_id=["48671","48671"]`

I need to parse it somehow so that I can actually access the array listed.

I've tried:

```
try {
  console.log(JSON.parse(productIDs))
} catch(e) { console.log(e) }
```

However it always kicks back with: 
`[SyntaxError: Unexpected token p]`

**Question: how can I convert this string into an array?**

Comment: instead of trying to work around a json error, can't you make the string you want to parse a valid json..?

Comment: maybe he doesn't have control over the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's **simply not JSON**. This would be JSON:

```
{ "product_category_id": ["48671","48671"] }
```

To wit:

```
JSON.parse('{ "product_category_id": ["48671","48671"] }')
// <- object
```

If you must parse that format for whatever reason, I'd do the following.

```
var products = 'product_category_id=["48671","48671"]';
var json = products.replace(/^product_category_id=/, '');
var ids = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(ids);
// <- ["48671","48671"]
```

Comment: Awesome. Yeah I tried adding `{` and `}` to it but I just realized that I forgot the double quotes. Thats why it didnt work. I just `replace()` the beginning and its all good

Comment: I'd advise, if possible, to convert the text to JSON rather than manipulating the string by hand

Comment: For some reason I didnt even consider `JSON.stringify()`. Thanks man